# Getting the last month date's data in sql

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, amazon-redshift

I have the below query to get the last month date's data. Suppose if today is `23rd Dec`, then it fetches `23rd Nov` data. But when it's `31st Dec`, then there would be no `31st Nov`. In that case it should fetch `30th Nov` data.

So, I want to decrease one day and check the condition again and should fetch the data. In this scenario, suppose on `March 31st`, first that query even should check for `feb 31st`, then it should check for `feb 30`, then `29th` and so on until the valid date of that particular month.

**My current query:**

```
select * 
from dataTable 
where date(datecolumn)=date(add_months(DATE(sysdate-1) ,-1));
```

So, this only fetches last month's date data. So, can someone please suggest me how to check for the mentioned validation in the query and fetch the data?

Comment: Your current query is not a valid Postgres query. Are you sure you're using or aiming at Postgres?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev Sorry, I am testing this query in mysql at the moment and have to shift this query to postgres on the actual server.

Comment: And what should it fetch in case of december 30?

Comment: @PeterRing The same, On Dec 30 it should fetch Nov 30 and even on Dec 31 it should fetch Nov 30 as Nov 31 is not valid date.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT dateadd(mm, -1, Convert(Datetime, '2013-12-31')
```

Comment: Does this work with the condition even ? Like if it's Oct 31st, it should fetch Sep 30 as Sep 31st is not valid.

Comment: just execute it. I think you don't need any condition just pass the date.